# How to remove additional commas in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Given a list like below

```
ListA=['apples', ',', 'orange', ',', 'grapes']
```

How to remove the ',' to get an output like below

```
ListA=['apples' , 'orange', 'grapes']
```

Comment: `ListA=['apples', ',' 'orange', ',' 'grapes']` is not a valid list. Did you mean `ListA=['apples', ',', 'orange', ',', 'grapes']`

Comment: That isn't a well formed list

Comment: @NikhilCSB it is a valid list

Comment: a better option would be to look at how this list is created, and create it correctly ... rather than constantly fight with some other malformed part

Comment: @NikhilCSB corrected, was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = ['apples', ',', 'orange', ',', 'grapes']

x = list(filter(lambda v: v != ',', x))

print(x)
```

another alternative:

```
x = [v for v in x if v != ',']
```

results in:

```
['apples', 'orange', 'grapes']
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to solve it by using `remove`:

```
ListA.remove(',')
```

Output:

```
['apples', 'orange', ',', 'grapes']
```

Or use a list comprehension for multiple "removals":

```
List_filtered = [x for x in ListA if x != ',']
```

Output:

```
['apples', 'orange', 'grapes']
```

Comment: except the actual list item is `',' 'orange'` which becomes `',orange'`

Comment: I assume OP didn't correctly place the `,` after the `','`. Otherwise, it's not a valid format to work with at all.

Comment: that is not true ... `' a'  'asd' ` becomes `' aasd'` in python ... although your assumption that he misspoke on what his list looks like is reasonable

Comment: You are correct, I still keep my assumption in place, but will work to provide an answer in case the OPs format is actually true. Thanks for pointing it out Joran.

Comment: one other asside I *think* `str.remove` will only remove first occurance :P

Answer (score 1):

use `string.strip`

```
l=['apples', ',' 'orange', ',' 'grapes']
res = [i.strip(',') for i in l]
print(res)
```

output

```
['apples', 'orange', 'grapes']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListB = [ListA[i] for i in range(0, len(ListA),2)]
```

Or

```
print([ListA[i] for i in range(0, len(ListA),2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

A Resul of strip(',') operation:

```
['apples', '', 'orange', '', 'grapes']
```

Not `['apples', 'orange', 'grapes']` !!!

Comment: this result is based on user input, see his edit history, plus i suggest you to make all your answer in one answer part not in multiple